# IE8 and IE9 compatible statement for el.nextSibling.contains(e.target)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm looking for a analogue to `if (! el.nextSibling.contains(e.target) )`, unsure what jQuery alternative there may be that works and will support IE8 and IE9

I've tried `$.contains($(el).next(), e.target)` and variations, but I'm hitting a wall. Any suggestions?

EDIT - the event in this case is a click:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  [].forEach.call(myMenu.open, function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        myMenu.activate(e);
    }, false);
  });
}
```

...

```
'activate': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var open = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');


    [].forEach.call(open, function(el) {
      if (!el.nextElementSibling.contains(e.target) && el != e.target) {
        console.log('Do something');
      }
    }
}
```

SECOND UPDATE:
I'm now going about this differently - I was able to reference the parentNode and achieve the same effect I wanted, which is supported in IE8 and IE9. E.G.:

```
if (!el.parentNode.contains(e.target) && el != e.target) {
```

Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: well how do you get the event object? What is the code that wraps this statement? Is there an error message?

Comment: The event object is passed into the function. To give you an idea, this code works in IE10+, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc, just not in IE9 and IE8 due to their limitations with JS:

if (!el.nextElementSibling.contains(e.target) && el != e.target) {

Comment: Is this article helpful, in your case: http://ericleads.com/2013/10/javascript-string-contains/ ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!el.parentNode.contains(e.target) && el != e.target) {
```

works for my situation and is supported by IE8 and IE9